# Is it possible to check if a key is in another key and if it is add the values of that key into the other key

Tags: python, dictionary, set

given a dictionary is it possible to check if key is inside any other key and if it is adds the values of the key into that other key
my_dict[key] = set()

for example

```
{'0': {'3', '1', '0'}, '3': {'3', '1', '4'}, '1': {'2', '1', '0'}, '5': {'3', '5'}}
```

since key '0" is in key '1': {'2', '1', '0'} then the values of key '0' gets added to key '1'

```
{0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 1, 2, 3}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 5: {1, 3, 4, 5}}
```

ive tried making putting the keys into a list and then checking if the values in the list is in any of the sets for the keys

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each set and use `dict.get` to extract items from a key if it exists, or fall back to the item itself:

```
d = {0: {3, 1, 0}, 3: {3, 1, 4}, 1: {2, 1, 0}, 5: {3, 5}}
print({k: {c for i in s for c in d.get(i, [i])} for k, [*s] in d.items()})
```

This outputs, in no particular order (since set is unordered in Python):

```
{0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 1, 2, 3}, 5: {1, 3, 4, 5}}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/LinedUnnaturalApi